# Export Chrome bookmarks from iPhone

Tags: google-chrome, iphone

How do I export iPhone Chrome bookmarks to html file? 
I have a computer with non-syncing Chrome bookmarks. I have bookmarks stored on iPhone. How do I export iPhone bookmarks?

Comment: Have you tried enabling sync on Chrome so that the bookmarks get synced to your computer? Please specify your operating system.

Comment: Yes. Can not sync with chrome on pc due to group policy on computer. Can not remove group policy. Need to export from phone.